# Need to improve the quality of images with GIMP

Tags: gimp, jpg

I have a number of jpg images whose quality I would like to improve. It is planned to both print them and use them in digital format. I guess to use the GIMP or another programm that I can install in my Linux. I expect you to advise me a tutorial with relevant information.  I have reduced original images with ImageMagick's `convert` command for posting here. These are scans of award documents from the Second World War in Russian.[image: doc_1.jpg]

[image: doc_2.jpg][image: doc_3.jpg]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "improving the quality" in this case? Are you trying to make the text more readable?

Comment: Yes, I want the text to be more readable both through the projector and when printed on paper

Comment: check also this one https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29901/gimp-how-to-remove-background-noise-artifacts-and-enhance-handwritten-text

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Users are happy to **assist**. But, this isn't a "tutorial on demand" site.

Comment: @Scott - I try the algorithm that the user xenoid described to me. It takes me time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The simple technique

Use the [Curves tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-curves.html).

If you look at the [image histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram):

- The hump (1) is a peak frequency of dark pixels and is your text
- The hump (2) is a peak frequency of light pixels and is your background
- No pixels beyond (3) because your background is rather dark.

So with Curves, you make a diagonal between (A) (everything darker will be pure black) and (B) everything lighter will be white. You can make the curve follow a slight "S" shape to improve contrast.

An inconvenient of that method is that it is limited by 1) color shifts and 2) darker parts of the background that make it hard to handle the text correctly.

[image]

### A more efficient technique (Gimp 2.10)

- Decompose the image into frequency components: *Filters>Enhance>Wavelet decompose*. YOU get  alayer group called "Decomposition". Each layer of this group contains a part of the image. The top layers are the fine detail (the text) while the bottom layers are the general image (the paper).
- You can easily clean most of your background and make it white by bucket-filling the "Residual" layer with white. You can also tryo to bucket-fill the layer immediately above it.
- You can add "sharpness" to you image by duplicating the "Scale 1" layer (and sometimes the "Scale 2" one as well).
- However, your text is not very dark, so create a new layer from all this (*Layer>New from visible*) and move it to the top of the layer stack.
- Then you can use Curves as above, making a diagonal where the bottom point is where the histogram stops to the left (you can leave the other point in the top right corner). You can also add some contrast with an S-shaped curve.

[image]

Comment: II did as suggested by xenoid and got results satisfying me.

Comment: Then you can "accept" the the answer (click the gray checkmark) :). Out of  curiosity, which technique did you use?

Comment: First, I applied the algorithm that you cited under point "A more efficient technique (Gimp 2.10)"; then I applied the one under paragraph "The simple technique" for all three photographs. This gave acceptable results that can be printed on a printer - the background does not become as dark as in the original photographs. Of course, you need to look for a compromise between sharpness and lightness. I also installed the G'Mic extension, as indicated in the link given by Luciano, but could not achieve any results with it.

Comment: Regarding the "more efficient technique", is there a good reason to fiddle with "Curves" in the end instead of just adjusting saturation with "Colors>Saturation"?

Comment: Another question: if i want to automate this procedure and make a command-line tool to remove background using "Wavelet decompose", could you suggest me where to start? I know there is Script-Fu, but learning it from scratch is hard. I know there is a Python library to work with wavelets, but i do not know how to implement with it an analog of "Wavelet decompose" from GIMP.

Comment: Question 1: This is typically used on near-monochrome images (black on some faintly colored background) so there is no saturation to work with.

Comment: Question 2: use Python, much easier to work with. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) for a large collection of python-fu scripts that you can use as examples (or steal code from). You can also ask questions on StackOverflow (with the "gimp" tag) or [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Forum-Scripting-questions)

Comment: Thanks for the links! Regarding question 1, i am trying to process color pictures of handwritten notes to make them printable and more readable, and here is what works the best so far: (1) wavelet decompose into 7 layers and bucket fill the background with white, (2) duplicate each of the 7 layers, (3) export. That's it.

Comment: I have found since that a better technique is to fill the "Residual" with its own average (Blur>pixellize and use the layer size). This often makes the final "Curves" step unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I present here a solution based on [xenoid](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/67201/xenoid)'s [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/132871) that so far gave me the most satisfactory results in clearing up image's background. (I am not sure if this is what the OP meant by "improving the quality", though.)

I only used the *Filters > Enhance > Wavelet-decompose...*, without *Colors > Curves...*.  Not having to play with color curves and image histograms simplifies the procedure IMO.

Here is what I did:

1. Use *Filters > Enhance > Wavelet-decompose...* with 7 scales.
2. Bucket fill *Residual* layer with the white or with a color of choice, or insert a layer with solid color above it.
3. Duplicate each of the *Scale* layers, except for the 7-th one.
4. Export as PNG or JPEG.

Here is how *Layers* dialog looks in the end:

[image]

Here are the results for the posted images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've decided to automate this procedure and created a Script-Fu script:

```lisp
; my-script-fu-white-out-background.scm
; last modified/tested by Alexey Muranov
; 31/12/2020 on GIMP 2.10.20
;===========================================================================
;
; Installation:
; This script should be placed in the user or system-wide script folder.
;
;   Windows 7/10
;   C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\scripts
;   or
;   C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\scripts
;
;
;   Linux
;   /home/yourname/.config/GIMP/2.10/scripts  
;   or
;   Linux system-wide
;   /usr/share/gimp/2.0/scripts
;
;===========================================================================

(define WD-SCALES 7)  ; the number of scales for wavelet-decompose

(define (my-script-fu-white-out-background inImage inDrawable)

  (gimp-image-undo-group-start inImage)

  (plug-in-wavelet-decompose
    RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
    inImage
    inDrawable
    WD-SCALES  ; number of scales (1-7)
    TRUE  ; create a layer group to store the decomposition
    FALSE  ; do not add a layer mask to each scales layer
  )

  (gimp-context-set-background '(255 255 255))

  (let* ( (layers (gimp-image-get-layers inImage))
          (layer-array (cadr layers))
          (wd-layer-group (aref layer-array 0))
          (wd-layers (gimp-item-get-children wd-layer-group))
          (wd-layer-array (cadr wd-layers))
          (wd-residual-layer (aref wd-layer-array WD-SCALES)) )

    (gimp-drawable-fill wd-residual-layer BACKGROUND-FILL)

    (do ((i (- WD-SCALES 2) (- i 1)))
      ((< i 0))
      (let* ( (layer (aref wd-layer-array i))
              (duplicated-layer (car (gimp-layer-copy layer FALSE))) )
        (gimp-image-insert-layer inImage
                                 duplicated-layer
                                 wd-layer-group
                                 i)
      )
    )
  )

  (gimp-image-undo-group-end inImage)

  (gimp-displays-flush)
)

(script-fu-register
  "my-script-fu-white-out-background"  ; func name
  "White out background"  ; menu label
  (string-append
    "White out background using wavelet-decompose.\n"
    "Intended for improving readability of scanned text images."
  )  ; description
  "Alexey Muranov"  ; author
  "copyleft"  ; copyright notice
  "2020-12-31"  ; date created
  "*"  ; image type that the script works on
  SF-IMAGE    "Image"    0
  SF-DRAWABLE "Drawable" 0
)

(script-fu-menu-register
  "my-script-fu-white-out-background"
  "<Image>/My Script-Fu"
)
```